# Счетчик перестал корректно отображать значения

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Установлены кнопки "ПОДЕЛИТЬСЯ" на сайте https://crazykeys.ru

На ВК было более 2000 репостов, но сейчас 1. Подскажите пожалуйста, что случилось и как эту проблему решить?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, поменялся адрес главной страницы.

Все адреса в этом списке могут восприниматься социальной сетью, как разные страницы.

- http://example.org
- http://example.org/
- https://example.org
- http://www.example.org
- http://example.org/index.html
- http://example.org?utm_source=1

Соответственно, у них будут отдельные показатели счётчики лайков.

Решение – найти адрес, на котором сейчас максимальное количество лайков и явно указывать его в параметрах.

```
<div id="ya-share2" data-url="https://example.org/"></div>
```

Для Вконтакте посмотреть количество лайков можно с помощью такого запроса.

```
https://vk.com/share.php?act=count&url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F
```

В параметр `url` нужно подставить url-encoded адрес сайта.