# Не считаются репосты ВК (yandex share)

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Коллеги, привет!

На [странице](http://kolesa.ru/new_octavia) внизу стоят кнопки `yandex share`.
Отображается около 30 репостов ВК, в то время как по факту их более 800 (легко ищется в самом ВК по хештегу `#new_octavia`).

Поведение продолжается несколько дней (4 минимум).

Счетчик дефолтный от яндекс, никаких скриптов дополнительных или своего кода нет.

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять с чем это может быть связано.

Comment: Может он считает репосты сделанные только через Ваш сайт?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Счетчик перестал корректно отображать значения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624690/%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1):

При установке блок вы не указали явно, адресом какой страницы нужно делиться. По умолчанию блок берёт адрес страницы, на которой расположен.

В данном случае, это `kolesa.ru/new_octavia/`.

Если поискать по хэштегу во Вконтакте, можно обнаружить и другие ссылки, например `www.kolesa.ru/new_octavia/`. Для Вконтакте это разные страницы и счётчики для них отдельные.

Склеить счётчики разных страниц в один нельзя.

Чтобы избежать подобной ситуации в будущем, нужно явно указывать адрес страницы в атрибуте `data-url`.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это все же не наш случай.
Т.к. только что я заходил на страницу и он показал значение близкое к реальному. (>2000)
После обновления страницы, значение вновь слетело на 20 штук.

Дополнительным, хоть и слабым аргументом в пользу того что дело не (или не только) в URL является то, что ни по одному из вариантов URL  нет цифр более 30.

Answer (score 0):

В последнее время Яндекс начал добавлять слэш в конец URL'a если указан только домен.

Т.е. для параметра
`data-url="http://domain.com"`

Скрипт отправляет запрос как `http://domain.com/`

А для ВК и Одноклассников - это по сути разные страницы. Отсюда и ошибка в счетчиках