# Переезд сайта на HTTPS и Блок "Поделиться"

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день!

На данный момент сайт в стадии перехода на https. Полная склейка в Яндексе ещё не произошла, 301 редирект на https версию ещё не настроен. При этом используем Блок "Поделится" от Яндекса, и вот этот блок почему-то фиксирует и считает только http версию.

Надо ли в данном блоке что-то дополнительно настраивать, что бы корректно заработали счетчики?

Каковы шансы вернуться на прежние цифры http версии в счетчиках?

Comment: К сожалению, [нет](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/636807/210283).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не считаются репосты ВК (yandex share)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636456/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%92%d0%9a-yandex-share)

Comment: [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624690/%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/624820#624820) Тут ответ. Но как суммировать счётчики. Вот в чём вопрос

Answer (score 0):

[Счетчик перестал корректно отображать значения](http://%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Не знаю как прошлый комментарий отредактировать или удалить. Возможно кармы не хватает. Поэтому дублирую ссылку с описанием уже.